# CSS is not loading in IE but works in other browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My website works works in all browsers except IE. I've tested it in IE 7 - 11. The CSS does not load at all. What am I doing wrong? I've worked on sites with similar code and have never run into this issue.

Here's the HTML:

```
 <!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>#</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="css/responsive.gs.12col.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div id="header-wrapper" class="clearfix">
        <a class="main-logo"href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        <ul class="contact-nav">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/mail2.png">Email Us!</a></li>
            <li class="spacer">|</li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="img/phone.png">#</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>

    </header>

        <a id="dropdown" href="#" title="Click This Button"><img src="img/burger_button.png" alt="burger button"><p></p></a>

    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="navigation-bar" id="menu">
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="vip.html">VIP</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="careers.html">CAREERS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content" class="clearfix">


    <footer class="clearfix">





        <div class="footer_img">
        <img src="img/premier.png" alt="premier event">
        </div>

        <p>2006 - 2015 © Privacy Terms of use. All trademarks are property of their owners.</p>
    </footer>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/global.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow89.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).resize(function() {

  if ($(this).width() < 960) {

    $('.nav').hide();

  } else {

    $('.nav').show();

    }

});

   $('#dropdown').on('click',function(){

      $('.nav').slideToggle();

   });

})
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
body {
    font-family: "helvetica", arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url('../img/metallic_2.jpg');
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 240px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: .8em;
}

header ul li {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}

header ul {
    list-style-image: url('../img/phone.gif');
}

ul.social-media {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.social-media a:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}

#header-wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #000;
    background: url('../img/background_header.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    /* border-top: solid 5px orange; */
}

#header-wrapper ul{
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
}

#header-wrapper li {
    display: inline;
}

.main-logo img {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.contact-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.contact-nav a:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}

.contact-nav img {
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav {
    background: #333;
    clear: both;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: ;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px;
}

.nav li {
    display: ;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

.nav li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding:  10px 20px;
    /* background: #333; */
    width: 100%;
    transition: .3s;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.nav li a:hover {
    background: orange;
}

.nav li a.active {
    background: orange;
}

/*  .nav li a:hover {
    background-image: url('../img/background_nav.gif');
    background-position: center center;
}

.nav li a.active {
    background-image: url('../img/background_nav.gif');
    background-position: center center;
} */

#main-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url('../img/background_main2.jpg');
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.videoWrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
    float: none;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#main-content {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#main-content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.85em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    float: none;
}

#main-content p {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


#main-content h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: ;
}
.button {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 145px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #0071BC;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #006699;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    transition: .3s;
}

.button {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 145px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #0071BC;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #006699;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    transition: .3s;
}

.button:hover {
    background: rgb(251,176,59);
    border-bottom: solid 5px rgb(247,147,30);

}

.button1:hover {
    background: rgb(251,176,59);
    border-bottom: solid 5px rgb(247,147,30);

}

.button a, .button1 a {
    color: #fff;
    width: 145px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#secondary-content {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #eee9e9;
    padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px;
}

#secondary-content img {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#secondary-content p {
    font-weight: lighter;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.graphs {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 960px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.graphs img{
    width: 100%;
}

.image-holder {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.fifty {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

blockquote {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
}

.video img {
    top: 0;
}

.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}

footer {
    max-width: 960px;
    background-color: #333;
    background-image: url('../img/moonsurface.png'); 
    background-position:  0% 75%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

footer p {
    font-size: .8em;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px; 
}

footer ul li {
    display: inline;
}

.footer_img {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-right: 5%;
}

.footer_img img {
    width: 100%;
}

.social_media {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 2.5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.social_media ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.videos {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #eee9e9; /* -- #faebd7 alternate color -- */
    padding: 20px;
    /* border-top: solid 5px #483c32; */
}



@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    header ul {
    margin: 40px auto;
    font-weight: lighter;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}

header ul li {
    font-size: .9em;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

    header img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

header {
    max-width: 100%;
}


.image-holder {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}



#header-wrapper ul{
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    float: none;
}

.social_media {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.footer_img {
    width: 50%;
    float: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

}

@media all and (max-width: 959px) {

    #header-wrapper {
        background: none;
    }

    .main-logo img {
        margin-left: 16%;
        margin-right: 20%;
        float: none;
        width: 65%;
    }

    header ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    font-size: 1rem;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    }

    header ul li {
        font-size: 1rem;
        width: 95%;
    }

    .nav {
        height: 306px;
        display: none;
    }
    .nav li {
        float: none;
        height: 51px;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main-content h2 {
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }

#dropdown {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #0e2d42;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#dropdown img {
    background-position: center;
    height: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#dropdown p {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 6px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

    #main-content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    float: none;
}

.fifty {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

blockquote {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

.image-holder {
    max-width: 100%;
}

}




  /* First make sure the video thumbnail images are responsive. */
    .video img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

  /* 
  This is the starting grid for each video with thumbnails 5 across for the largest screen size.
  It's important to use percentages or there may be gaps on the right side of the page. 
  */
  .video {
    background: none;
    width: 31%; /* Thumbnails 3 across */
    margin: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 1%;
    float: left;
  }

   /* These keep the height of each video consistent between YouTube and Vimeo.
   Each can have thumbnail sizes that vary by 1px and are likely break your layout. */
  .video figure {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
}

    .video h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: #eee9e9;
        font-size: 1.25em;
        display: none;
    }

  /* Media Queries - This is the responsive grid. */
  @media all and (max-width: 960px) {
    .video {
      width: 23%; /* Thumbnails 4 across */
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .video {
      width: 48%; /* Thumbnails 2 across */
    }

  }
  @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .video {
      display: block;
      width: 96%; /* Single column view. */
      margin: 2%; /* The smaller the screen, the smaller the percentage actually is. */
      float: none;
    }
  }

  /* These are my preferred rollover styles. */
  .video img {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .video img:hover, .video img:active, .video img:focus {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
```

Comment: What Happens if you Include the CSS in the Head instead of linking it?

Comment: You've tested in five different versions of IE? Or just used IE11 developer tools to see how the page would render in an older browser? The latter is *not* the same as testing for native support in an older browser.

Comment: Could it be a cache issue? Clear your cache, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Also, validate your markup and CSS first. You have some invalid HTML in a few spots (no `alt=""` for your img tags, no height/width declared for your iframe, deprecated attributes in your iframe, etc.)

Comment: Oh yes, thanks definitely! The iframe is something that I'm still working on and I gotta add the alt attributes. I was just wanting to figure out what was wrong with the CSS and IE. It was a stupid mistake! lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your link attributes are incorrect. Instead of `type="type/css"`, you should use `type="text/css"`.

Comment: OMG. Thank you. I don't know what I was thinking when I typed that out. As soon as I changed it the site loaded correctly in IE. AGAIN, THANK YOU SO MUCH! haha

Answer (score 0):

The value `"text/css"` indicates that the content is CSS. The `<link>` tag goes inside the head section:

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

An external style sheet can be written in any text editor. The file should not contain any html tags. The style sheet file must be saved with a .css extension.